# How to extract two numbers from two strings and calculate the difference in Bash?

Tags: macos, bash-scripting, string-manipulation

I have a text file which contains (among others) the following lines:

```
{chapter}{{1}Einleitung}{27}{chapter.1}  
{chapter}{{2}Grundlagen}{35}{chapter.2}
```

How can I

- get the 2 lines from this text file (they will always contain `}Einleitung` resp. `}Grundlagen}` and
- extract the 2 page numbers (in this case 27 and 35),
- calculate the difference `35-27 = 8` and
- save the difference (`8`) of the two numbers in a variable

Perhaps with a bash script in Mac OS X?

Comment: `var=$({ grep -Eo '(Einleitung|Grundlagen)\}.[0-9]+.'|sort -r|tr '\n' ' '| tr -d -c '0-9 '|awk '{print $1 - $2}'; }</tmp/inputfile)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>I do not know if Mac OS X has awk. If it does, this should work:</s>

This should work:

```
DIFFERENZ=$(awk 'BEGIN {
  FS="[{}]+"
 } {
  if ($4=="Einleitung")
   EINLEITUNG=$5
  if ($4=="Grundlagen")
   GRUNDLAGEN=$5
 } END {
   print GRUNDLAGEN-EINLEITUNG
 }' textfile)
```

How it works:

- `FS="[{}]+"` sets the field separator to any combination of curly brackets.
- `$4` refers to the third filed on the line (separated by curly brackets).
- `DIFFERENZ=$(...)` evaluates the command `...` and stores the ouput in `DIFFERENZ`.

Comment: it has: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/awk.1.html

Comment: thanks, that works well with my example. How do I have to write a chapter title which contains a space like `Ergebnisse und Diskussion`? I tried with `if ($3=="Ergebnisse und Diskussion")`, but that does not seem to find the correct line

Comment: @Martin: Spaces are treated as separators. `if ($3=="Ergebnisse" && $4=="und" && $5=="Diskussion")` should work. But the page number will no longer be stored in `$4`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank you for your help - sorry, I should have directly asked for the more complicated string, but I did not think about this possible complication

Comment: The problem was my `gsub`-hack. I have set the field separator properly, so `if ($4=="Ergebnisse und Diskussion")` should work now.

Comment: @Dennis: and now your answer looks like mine :)

Answer (score 3):

calc.awk:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="}{";           # split lines by '}{'
    e=0;               # set variable 'e' to 0
    g=0;               # set variable 'g' to 0
}

/Einleitung/ { e=$3; } # 'Einleitung' matches, extract the page
/Grundlagen/ { g=$3;}  # 'Grundlagen' matches, extract the page

END {
    print g-e;         # print difference
}
```

you can call it via:

```
$> awk -f calc.awk < in.txt
```

it will print `8`. you could store that number in a bash-variable like this:

```
$> nr=`awk -f calc.awk < in.txt`
```

if you need it more tight you could also rewrite `calc.awk` to be not a separate file but a one-line:

```
$> nr=`awk 'BEGIN{FS="}{";g=0;e=0}/Einleitung/{e=$3;}/Grundlagen/{g=$3;}END{print g-e;}' < in.txt`
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure bash 4.x, and shows the differences for every chapter:

```
unset page_last title_last page_cur title_cur
re='\{chapter\}\{\{[[:digit:]]+\}([^}]+)\}\{([[:digit:]]+)\}'
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $re ]]; then
        title_cur=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} page_cur=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        diff=$((page_cur-page_last))
        echo "${diff} pages between \"${title_last}\" and \"${title_cur}\""
        title_last=$title_cur page_last=$page_cur
    fi
done < "$myfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ DIFFERENCE=$(( $( cat FILENAME | grep Grundlagen | head -n1 | cut -c26-27 ) - $( cat FILENAME | grep Einleitung  | head -n1 | cut -c26-27 ) ))
$ echo $DIFFERENCE
8
```

This requires that the lines always look exactly like this (i.e. no different headline), because of the `cut`.

Comment: it wont even work with different numbers, lets say `1` or `100`

Comment: @akira If there are that many pages between introduction and fundamentals chapter headlines, he's doing something wrong :-) But you're right of course.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Thank you for your anwer! As you already state (and @akira says), the usage of this solution is quite limited because the numbers have to be exactly at the same position each time. The solutions with `awk` are more flexible.

Comment: @Martin While you're right, you never even hinted that e.g. you want to apply a solution to other chapter names. Quite the opposite with your first list item...

Comment: @DanielBeck: this is true - my question was incomplete.